# reduce large image loading time just like the photo library in iphone

Tags: iphone

Anybody know how to load the large image to become a blur image first and then only slowly load the full size of image. This will at least let the user to preview the image first other than waiting for a few second to load the full size image.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but just in case anyone is looking for it, there is a project called [NYXImagesKit](https://github.com/Nyx0uf/NYXImagesKit) that does what you are looking for.

It has a class named NYXProgressiveImageView that is a subclass of UIImageView.

All you have to do is:

```
NYXProgressiveImageView * imgv = [[NYXProgressiveImageView alloc] init];
imgv.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[imgv loadImageAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourimage"]];
[self.view addSubview:imgv];
[imgv release];
```

Also, a good option is to save your images as interlaced so that it loads with low quality and improve with the download. If the image is normal it is loaded from top to bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But the image is from camera roll not net. And the app needs to preview the image just like a photo gallery.If the image is large like 2000*4000,it will take seconds to load image use UIImage.